# how to distinct one column when using inner join

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, ms-access-2007

i am using two table postjob and job location
want to distinct jobtitle

The query is:

```
select postjob.jobtitle,
postjob.industry,
postjob.companyname,
postjob.jobdescription,
postjob.postid,
postjob.PostingDate,
Job_Location.Location,
Job_Location.PostigID 
from postjob 
inner join Job_Location 
on postjob.postid = Job_Location.PostigID 
Where postjob.industry=' Marketing, Advertising'
```

output of this query
http://www.justlocaldial.com/Industry_search.aspx?ind=Marketing,%20Advertising

Comment: please mention in detail as to what is required

Comment: i want to distinct jobtitle column

Comment: A distinct will be applied to all the fields in a query by default - do you (a) need all these fields, and (b) if not, please define your exact requirement.

Comment: i need all field but want to  distinct only jobtitle column

Comment: check this link:-http://www.justlocaldial.com/Industry_search.aspx?ind=Marketing,%20Advertising

Comment: @kusha: check sqlfiddle and fill data will try to find out

Comment: If your Job_Location table is giving multiple rows per jobtitle then you will need to use either the "First" or "Min" function against the fields of the second table to ensure it only returns one row.

Answer (score 1):

**Fill** the *data* as u want and also give us idea how data to display so we can try to find the solution;
you can distinct on postjob.postid  this gives unique data

live demo  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2d53c/4

```
create table postjob
(postid int identity(1,1),jobtitle nvarchar(50),industry nvarchar(30),
jobdescription nvarchar(150),PostingDate datetime)

insert into postjob values('Programmer','Software','User interface','2012-07-04 15:00:24.833')
insert into postjob values('Tester','Software','Automated Testing Application','2012-07-04 15:00:24.833')
insert into postjob values('Sales Executive','Marketing','Meeting with clients','2012-07-04 15:00:24.833')
insert into postjob values('Doctor','Hospitality','Treatment','2012-07-04 15:00:24.833')
insert into postjob values('Desinger','Software','User interface graphicdesinger','2012-07-04 15:00:24.833')
insert into postjob values('Desinger','Interior','Blah blah','2012-07-04 15:00:24.833')
```

---

```
create table Job_Location(PostigID int,Location nvarchar(50))
insert into Job_Location values ('1','India')
insert into Job_Location values ('2','Italy')
insert into Job_Location values ('3','Germany')
insert into Job_Location values ('4','France')
insert into Job_Location values ('5','India')
insert into Job_Location values ('6','USA')
```